# ionic app doesn't take code changes any more

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app and to login by email and password.
i have config.constant.ts file which is contain the URL to login service and main-service.ts file to make the HTTP request.
when i change the URL it didn't work it still as first edit and didn't take changes anymore.

This is config.constant.ts

```
export const URL_ROOT = 'http://myipaddress:8080/estore/rest/main';
```

This is the login method in main-service.ts

```
loginDriver(email,password){
    return this.http.get(`${URL_ROOT}/loginDriver/${email}/${password}`).map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you don't use your constant.

Just include it in your URL to make it absolute.

```
this.http.get(`${URL_ROOT}/loginDriver/${email}/${password}`)
```

...and don't forget to import it before

Just a side remark: I don't think putting the password in the URL is a good idea.

Comment: I mean if i change the URL_ROOT form :'http://myipaddress:8080/estore/rest/main' to 'http://myipaddress:8080/fuberdriver/rest/main' in the browser console still hit on 'http://myipaddress:8080/estore/rest/main'

Comment: @MoathWafeeq are you sure that you correctly import your constant so it is defined when you try to evaluate your URL?

Comment: Yes, this is the import import "{ URL_ROOT } from '../../config.constant';"

Comment: @MoathWafeeq ...and a `console.log(URL_ROOT)` displays the expected value?